# Nginx send dynamic subdomain to upstream server

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a question regarding the proxy_pass and dynamic subdomains.

on my server, I have a site_block which looks like this:

```
upstream mydockersite{
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name ~^review-+(?<subdomain>.+)\.website\.com;

         location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                proxy_pass http://mydockersite;
        }

}
```

Which works fine with redirecting incoming requests, made to my server to my docker container which is also a NGINX server.

For example:

`http://review-xyz.website.com`

Or

`http://review-somedynamicsubdomain.website.com`

Or

`http://review-anothersubdomain.website.com`

Where the `review-` portion is fixed
the `<subdomain>` portion could be anything
and `website.com` is my domain anyway.

I see that the whole request domain can be passed to the server in my docker container with the header that I set `proxy_set_header Host $host;` but I have no idea how to grab them in the config of my docker nginx server and redirect to the requested `root` folder.

The configuration of the nginx server which is in my docker container looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    
    ######## MY PROBLEM IS HERE ########
    root /home/site_reviews/main; 
    ####################################        

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

At the line:
`root /home/site_reviews/main;`
I need to replace the `main` portion with the `<subdomain>` portion of the `proxy_pass`

So the `root` folder where the website is being served from will be the subdomain

For example if I have an URL like this: `review-x34kk4ids.website.com`,
then my docker container nginx should serve the folder `x34kk4ids` which is in the docker folder `/home/site_reviews/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since I didn't get any answer, I found the solution myself and here is how I solved the problem:

This would be the nginx site-block for the dynamic subdomains:

```
upstream reiviewcontainer{
 server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ~^review-+(?<subdomain>.+)\.website\.com;

     location / {
            
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;

            ###This line is my solution###
            proxy_set_header Review $subdomain;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            proxy_pass http://reiviewcontainer;
    }
 }
```

I created an upstream which points to `127.0.0.1` on port `8081`. This is the port where the docker container nginx server is listening to.

Then I create a new custom header which is sent to the nginx server in the docker container with the name `Review` and the value of the dynamic subdomain:
`proxy_set_header Review $subdomain;`

And then the container uses the passed subdomain in the header to the correct document root like this:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 index index.php index.html;

 ### grab the subdomain from the header and set to a variable
 set $folder $http_review;

 ### set root folder of website according to the passed subdomain
 root /home/reviews/$folder/public;

 location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
 }

 location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  gzip_static on;
 }
}
```

note that the custom header which is sent to the nginx server in the docker container is called `Review` but in the nginx server in the docker container I grab it with `http_review` and set it to a variable named `$folder` and then can use that dynamic subdomain as I want.